# How to Change Page Layout in SharePoint WSS Site

Tags: sharepoint, layout, wss

In SharePoint WSS (not MOSS) how can I change the page layout for an existing page?

All the best

Answer (score 5):

On the page editing bar, select page settings from the page menu item. From there, you can select the page layout used in the same way you did when the page was created. All your data (text, webparts etc) should still remain in place.

Not sure what happens to web parts if the new page layout doesn't have corresponding zones though, so be careful there.

**update for WSS specific details**

WSS doesn't support page layouts (as they are known in MOSS) as they're installed as part of the web publishing feature in MOSS.

WSS pages are instanced off the aspx page *templates* defined in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\1033\STS\DOCTEMP\SMARTPGS.

These are based off the site master page and are (effectively) standard aspx pages. You can't change the template that's used - the page exists on the site once it's created.

You can modify the page on the file system, and as long as the page isn't ghosted, all the pages using that template will be updated.

Comment: This is only the case with MOSS publishing enabled, I'm looking for how to do this in WSS. Cheers

Comment: When I look at the page in the pages library it tells me that it's page layout is Blank Web Part Page. The site has publishing enabled but this is not a publishing page - it is the home page that is created by the blank site template. Does that make sense?

Comment: Blank Web Part Page is one of the default layouts that the MOSS publishing feature installs. You should have the page editing toolbar; Page Settings on the Page menu there should give you the option to pick a layout. Do you get the page editing toolbar when editing a page?

Comment: Not on this page as it is the initial page created by the blank site template, which I think isn't a publishing page - so I just get the stop editing option when the page is in edit mode.

Comment: Creating a blank site should create a blank WSS site (even on a MOSS installed server). The site created shouldn't have the publishing feature installed so shouldn't have any page layouts or even a pages library (just created one on a MOSS server to confirm this).

Comment: Maybe check that the publishing feature is enabled - maybe it was once a publishing site, but the feature was disabled and the pages were left in a weird limbo-like state between WSS & MOSS?

Comment: Marcus, I think it was a WSS blank site initially. Then I turned on the publishing features. Now the home page is not a publishing page. Can I change it's page layout or is that not possible? Cheers

Comment: Probably not, the home page is still a *normal* page and not a pub page. You'll probably have to create a new pub page and set that as the home page for the site (Site Settings / Look & Feel / Welcome Page). You'll also have to move your content onto it I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint designer is the best way of editting a page layout, or creating a new one. It's also the best way of creating/editting a master page too, if that's what you mean.

Note that in SharePoint designer you can also 'Detach' a Publishing Page from a Page Layout, so that you can change it's layout without affecting all pages using that page layout.

However, if you want to package these up for deployment across systems, you're looking at needing visual studio - or being really confident in NotePad!

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [SharePoint designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/FX100487631033.aspx) to change an existing Aspx page.

What exactly do you want to change in a page?

Comment: I'm trying to change the page layout associated with the page. Cheers